# Handling external function imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

This might be a rather general question on how to handle imports of external functions and exporting functions.

So I have a `component` like this:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {handleChange} from "./path";
//imports from different files...

class Foo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.bindFunctions();

        this.state = {...};
    };

    //Arrow functions to bind them
    alreadyBound = () => {};

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Some text
            </div>
        );
    }

    bindFunctions = () => {
        this.handleChange = handleChange.bind(this);
        //dozens of functions to follow...
    }
}

export default compose(
    translate('translations'),
    connect()
)(Foo);
```

This is how my external functions look like (They are not part of a `component`, just files with functions to be reused in various `components`):

```
export function handleChange(value, {target: {name, type}}) {
    this.setState({[name]: value});
}
```

Now this works perfectly fine but it's nauseating. My files grow in size and it's a pain to always `bind` those functions. I get the necessity of importing the functions/components, but do I really have to `bind` them in this fashion? Something like `arrow` functions would be neat and would save me lot of redundant typing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd refactor the thing either as a set of mixins ( adding handleChange,... ) or as non member functions ( handleChange( this, value, target ) ); if you use these as events, then mixins being the only alternative

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes I'd like to relinquish on member functions or passing `this`, since this style is outdated. What do you mean by mixins?

Comment: theres a nice talk about it [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3040)

Comment: `.bind()` is not neccessary here...

Comment: @Jonasw True, but I still have to type another line of code. It saves me a couple of annoying chars though, thanks.

Comment: a mixin is a sort of abstract subclass ( just google it ), anyway I'll add an answer to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could import multiple methods at once like this:

```
import * as path from  "./path";

class Foo { }
```

Then we can assign them as static methods:

```
Object.assign( Foo, path );
```

or as prototype methods:

```
Object.assign( Foo.prototype, path );
```

If you want to bind the context its a bit more difficult. That could be done in the constructor:

```
import * as path from  "./path";

class Foo { 
  constructor(){
    for(var key in path) this[key] = path[key].bind(this);
  }
  //...
}
```

Or if you just want a few functions to be bound ( maybe faster ) :

```
import * as path from  "./path";

class Foo { 
  constructor(){
    const bind = ["onClick","onResize" /* whatever*/];
    for(var key of bind) this[key] = this[key].bind(this);
  }
}

Object.assign(Foo, path.prototype);
```

Comment: Works like charm. However, `Object.assign( Foo, path );` this doesn't

Comment: Yes, there are. `this.myFunction is not a function` e.g. when calling it from `componentDidMount`. With `prototype` it works

Comment: @nocebo yes thats for *as static methods* . Its like `class Foo { static test(){} }` , so you can do `Foo.test()`

Comment: So is there any disadvantage with `prototype`. Or a best practice for using one or the other?

Comment: @nocebo no they are different. The first method assigns *static* methods, so they are available only directly at the class itself ( aka `Foo.sth()` ). The other ones ( prototype methods or just methods) are part of *class instances* so `foo = new Foo(); foo.method()`

Comment: @nocebo [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)) calls the *static methods* *class methods*

Comment: @Nocebo, ... uhm, I don't think this is equivalent to your original code, because 'path' functions *are not* bound to the component instance as arrow property functions are; this means that your code won't work if you pass those functions as react events ... ( assuming this was your orignal intent of course )

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes You are right. A lot of functions work properly, however, like you said, passing those 'path' functions as react events doesn't work. Do you know a simple workaround, or do I have to rely on mixins?

Comment: @Nocebo, in the constructor you could add something like

`for( fun in path ) this[fun].bind(this);`

Answer (score 1):

as an alternative design, you may consider a mixin, eg something like:

```
let clickable = (superclass) => class extends superclass {  

    constructor(props) { super(props); };

    handleClick = () => { console.log( "clicked ", this ); };
};

class Foo extends clickable(Component) {
    constructor(props) { super(props); this.state = { ... };};

    render() { return <div onClick={this.handleClick}>foobar</div>; }
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to reduce his loc. I don't see how this reduces the loc?

Comment: @Felix, because there's no need to manually bind the mixin members to 'this' as he's doing now ... ( look at the //dozens of functions to follow... line )

Comment: This seems fancy, but I'm hesitant to introduce such new constructs and rather work with what I already have

Comment: @Nocebo, mixins are pretty standard I suppose; if you want a react looking alternative, take a look at higher order components ...