# Performance issues on importing functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I previously asked a question on how to handle the `imports` of external functions from external files [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46407004/handling-external-function-imports/46407809).

Now the solution was either doing this
`Object.assign( Foo.prototype, path );`, which fails whenever you want to use those functions as react events like @MassimilianoJanes already pointed out.

Or this, which I prefered:

```
import * as path1 from "./path1";
import * as path2 from "./path2";
import * as path3 from "./path3";
// and so on...

class Foo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.bindFunctions();
        this.state = {...};
    };

    bindFunctions = () => {
        for(var key in path1) this[key] = path1[key].bind(this); // This binds all functions from the file "./path1" to Foo
        for(var key in path2) this[key] = path2[key].bind(this); // This binds all functions from the file "./path2" to Foo
        for(var key in path2) this[key] = path3[key].bind(this); // This binds all functions from the file "./path3" to Foo
    }

    render() {...}
}
```

Now my questions mostly concern the performance of my application.

Let's say I have a few files (`path1`, `path2`, `path3`, ...) with dozens of functions each and I simply import it this way. Presumably, whenever `Foo` is called it binds all the functions in `bindFunctions`, even though I only use a couple of functions of each file in `Foo`.

Now here are my questions:

1. Does this cause significant performance issues?
2. Are the `imports` triggered only once (e.g. when the app builds) or every time the component is called?
3. Does this affect the size of the project in any way?
4. What are the general downsides of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the functions you want to use in advance?

Comment: @Ursus Yes, I do know them. But I need dozens of them (not all), yet I'd like to renounce on importing them one by one, hence the `for` loop over all of them.

Comment: I can't help thinking a setup that needs to import dozens of functions isn't standard. I checked your other question and I agree with Massimiliano Janes: you may want reconsidering the architecture of the app. [Higher Order Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) achieve what you need and are standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this cause significant performance issues?

Creating new functions using `bind` for every single instance is an issue indeed. Whether it's more on memory or more on performance I can't say, but most of the times it's *not significant* anyway. If you do have a significant number of instances/instantiations though, you will want to avoid this.

> Are the imports triggered only once (e.g. when the app builds) or every time the component is called?

Modules are evaluated only once.

> whenever `Foo` is called it binds all the functions in `bindFunctions`, even though I only use a couple of functions of each file in Foo.

So just don't do that! Use the `Object.assign( Foo.prototype, path );` approach, and then only bind those methods that you actually need bound.

Comment: To the last point. "Couple" still means dozens. I'd like to avoid importing every single one, but I see the issue here. Thanks!

Comment: The performance issue is not about importing them, as stated the imported module is evaluated only once and the result is reused. Also just `Object.assign` them once to the prototype. Do only the `bind` calls in the instance constructor.

Comment: Also, there might be something wrong with your design if you have a class that is too large to fit into a single file, and has dozens of methods that are used as event handlers somewhere. Abstract, simplify, and compose from smaller elements.

Comment: Sorry wanted to say `bind` instead of `importing` As stated at the beginning. `Object.assign` to the prototype doesn't work whenever you want to use the function as a react event (e.g. handleChange on a input tag)

Comment: @Nocebo But as you said, not all of them. Do `Object.assign(Foo.prototype, methods)`, and then in the constructor `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);`. You should not need many of those.

Comment: Yes, I know. But the application isn't that small for that I only have one event handler. I have dozens of input fields that need specific handlers since they vary in logic. I like your approach and I will implement it, I just don't like typing `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);` for all my event handlers :)

Comment: Maybe you should make one component for each input? Also do the handlers really vary that much in logic, can't you abstract some of it into a shared handler? (The obvious single-handler solution would be event delegation, where the handler logic is switched depending on the current event's target element)

Comment: I thought about doing this and I use one event handler for most input fields. But some of them very much vary in logic. (They target fields in arrays/handlers for third party lib e.g datepicker etc). So whenever I can rely on my simple event handler I will, but I do need some that vary.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Does this cause significant performance issues?

That depends entirely on what `Foo` is, and how often it is instantiated.

> 2. Are the imports triggered only once (e.g. when the app builds) or every time the component is called?

The imports are triggered only once.

> 3. Does this affect the size of the project in any way?

It slightly affects the memory impact, as each bound function is kinda like a distinct function. Therefore this needs slightly more memory than just storing a reference to the original function. But I'd doubt that this is of any significance. You should have to instantiate A LOT of `Foo`s to have a significant memory impact due to this.

> 4. What are the general downsides of doing this?

That you bind and store a lot of functions you'll never use.

> Presumably, whenever Foo is called it binds all the functions in bindFunctions, even though I only use a couple of functions of each file in Foo.

So how about binding them lazily? something like that:

```
import * as path1 from "./path1";
import * as path2 from "./path2";
import * as path3 from "./path3";
// and so on...

class Foo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {...};
    };

    render() {...}
}

const eventHandler = Object.assign(Object.create(null), path1, path2, path3);
Object.keys(eventHandler).forEach(prop => {
    Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, prop, {
        get(){
            return eventHandler[prop].bind(this) ;
        }
    });
});
```

or maybe this, where it lazily replaces the getter with the bound functions.

```
Object.keys(eventHandler).forEach(prop => {
    Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, prop, {
        configurable: true,
        get(){
            var value = eventHandler[prop].bind(this) ;
            Object.defineProperty(this, prop, { value });
            return value;
        }
    });
});
```

*Yet I still don't like the idea to add all these methods if you already know that you'll never use most of them; just out of lazyness.*